# How to pass generic into this method

Tags: java, generics

I have method look like

```
doSomething( Class<T> valueType)
```

i call pass value like

> Map.class, Long.class

as parameter into above method. If i want to use generic.  how should i pass the value into above method?  `doSomething(Class<Map>);`  doesnt work

Comment: `Class<Map>` is a type not a variable.

Comment: you might be attempting ? doSomething(Class<? extends T> clazz); if you're trying to enforce a class of maps. I am not quite sure what you're after though. <T> is the class of the generic. A List<Long> enforces the type <Long>, Class<T> statement generally are factory methods of some sort an instantiate classes. Read the documentation--that's you're best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map.class` returns an object of type `Class<Map>`, `Long.class` returns an object of type `Class<Long>`.

So to pass `Map.class` your T needs to me Map.
If you want your T to be a generic, say `ArrayList<String>`, then that's not possible.
The reason is that generics in Java use type erasure, which means that the generic type is only there at compile time, but it's erased at run time. Thus there doesn't exists something like `ArrayList<String>.class`.

Java generics are quite different that C# generics in this sense.